# Lua: Sort table of numbers with multiple dots

Tags: lua

I have a table of strings like this:

```
{
    "1",
    "1.5",
    "3.13",
    "1.2.5.7",
    "2.5",
    "1.3.5",
    "2.2.5.7.10",
    "1.17",
    "1.10.5",
    "2.3.14.9",
    "3.5.21.9.3",
    "4"
}
```

And would like to sort that like this:

```
{
    "1",
    "1.2.5.7",
    "1.3.5",
    "1.5",
    "1.10.5",
    "1.17",
    "2.2.5.7.10",
    "2.3.14.9",
    "2.5",
    "3.5.21.9.3",
    "3.13",
    "4"
}
```

How do I sort this in Lua? I know that `table.sort()` will be used, I just don't know the function (second parameter) to use for comparison.

Comment: `table.sort(t, function (a,b) return a<b end )` or just `table.sort(t)`

Comment: Since you already know you have to write a comparison function, please make an attempt at that and include that in the question, so we can see where you're having trouble.

Comment: @MikeV.: The default `<` would put `"1.10"` before `"1.5"`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given your requirements, you probably want something like [natural sort order](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natural_sort_order). I described several possible solution as well as their impact on the results in [a blog post](http://notebook.kulchenko.com/algorithms/alphanumeric-natural-sorting-for-humans-in-lua).

The simplest solution may look like this (below), but there are 5 different solutions listed with different complexity and the results:

```lua
function alphanumsort(o)
  local function padnum(d) return ("%03d%s"):format(#d, d) end
  table.sort(o, function(a,b)
    return tostring(a):gsub("%d+",padnum) < tostring(b):gsub("%d+",padnum) end)
  return o
end
```

Answer (score 0):

`table.sort` sorts ascending by default. You don't have to provide a second parameter then. As you're sorting strings Lua will compare the strings character by character. Hence you must implement a sorting function that tells Lua which comes first.

> I just don't know the function (second parameter) to use for
> comparison.

That's why people wrote the [Lua Reference Manual](https://www.lua.org/manual/5.4/manual.html#pdf-table.sort)

> **table.sort (list [, comp])**
>
> Sorts the list elements in a given order, in-place, from list[1](https://www.lua.org/manual/5.4/manual.html#pdf-table.sort) to
> list[#list]. If comp is given, then it must be a function that
> receives two list elements and returns true when the first element
> must come before the second in the final order, so that, after the
> sort, i <= j implies not comp(list[j],list[i]). If comp is not given,
> then the standard Lua operator < is used instead.
>
> The comp function must define a consistent order; more formally, the
> function must define a strict weak order. (A weak order is similar to
> a total order, but it can equate different elements for comparison
> purposes.)
>
> The sort algorithm is not stable: Different elements considered equal
> by the given order may have their relative positions changed by the
> sort.

Think about how you would do it with pen an paper. You would compare each number segment. As soon as a segment is smaller than the other you know this number comes first.

So a solution would probably require you to get those segments for the strings, convert them to numbers so you can compare their values...